# Alternative to Singleton Pattern for an application settings manager

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, settings, application-settings

I've read all of the reasons why Singletons cause problems in code, but I can't find an alternative in the following scenario.

I have a Java Swing Application. The user can set settings through the GUI that effect both the display and functionality of the application, and these settings are stored and retrieved from an XML config file. When the application is loaded, a SettingsManager object is constructed. In the constructor, the settings manager parses the XML config file and stores all of the settings locally for quick access (I'll call this a cache). When a setting is changed in the application, the setting is immediately written to file but the cache is updated at the same time.

## The Problem

If multiple instance of the settings manager are created, when one setting is changed in one instance, the cache of the others becomes stale. Without using a singleton, one possible way to fix this would be to not use a cache and simply always retrieve settings from the file. This isn't a horrible idea, but it's not preferable. If I did this I think I'd have to put in some extra work to make it thread safe as well.

## Why a Singleton helps

If SettingsManager is Singleton, there is only one cache, so it can never be stale. However, I can see already that this isn't a good idea as it's now essentially a global variable, and classes that don't need to access settings can now access them. And from what I've been reading there's plenty of other problems.

So is there some other way to design this that solves the problem without using a Singleton?

Comment: Classes that need to access settings should have been injected with them.

Comment: You can use a static global variable... or have some kind of manager class and pass around the instance of the object.  You could also implement some kind of reference counting scheme and limit this class to one instance.

Comment: You can use a dependency injection library to get access to a single instance of your class without implementing Singleton.

Comment: Singletons were created to solve the problems of static global variables.

Comment: here you can read about singleton and dependency injection: http://www.androidsx.com/cant-test-that-singleton-try-dependency-injection/ and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246963/practical-singleton-dependency-injection-question

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it so that the SettingsManager is managed as a Singleton internally in a class (this class obviously wont be a singleton), and this class instance will only be injected into those classes that need it. A handle-body (AKA bridge) would work well.

This would give you the best of both:

- the SettingsManager is only instantiated once and so is its cache. And the cache wont ever be stale.
- Only the objects that need it will have access to it

Obviously this handle-body class (or any other solution) could be instantiated anywhere, circumventing the dependency injection. So Im not sure if the perfect solution to this problem exists, but this could get you a few steps closer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me follow up on Brady's answer and suggest that the method on the "handle-body" class be declared **protected**.  This would limit its availability.  Another technique would be to put the class in a package that contains the name "internal" (e.g. com.mycorp.abc.internal).  That may not limit access, but it does send a clear message to other developers that the class/method really shouldn't be used.